# Cannot read property 0 of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Quisiera saber porque tengo este error, lo que pasa es que estoy usando un código para captar datos desde una clase padre. Cuando ejecuto este código, todo funciono hasta cuando le puse para archivos. 
Quisiera saber cual sería el error, ya que si solo es texto funciona correctamente.
Este es mi código:

```js
$(".form-devolucion-dvl").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let elemento = $(this);
  let padre = elemento.closest('.modal-body');

  let idtramite = padre.find(".idtramite").val();
  let tramitedoc = padre.find(".documentot").val();
  let archivotra = padre.find(".frmfile").prop("files")[0];

  var datosactualizar = new FormData();
  datosactualizar.append("idtramite", idtramite);
  datoseliminar.append("tramitedoc", tramitedoc);
  datosactualizar.append("archivotra", archivotra);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "consultas/actualizar.php",
    data: datosactualizar,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(r) {
      r = r.trim();
      if (r == "true") {

        swal({
          type: 'success',
          title: 'Tramite Corregido con éxito'
        }).then(function() {
          location.reload();
        });

      } else if (r == "false") {

        swal({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Error al Actualizar, volver a intentar por favor'
        });

      }

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal form-devolucion-dvl mt-3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-body">

    <input type="hidden" name="frmid" class="idtramite" value="2" required="required" />
    <input type="hidden" name="frmdoc" class="documentot" value="archivos/hola.jpg" required="required" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="frmcorregir" disabled>Hola</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input frmfile" name="frmfile">
      <label class="custom-file-label form-control">Selecciona Archivo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
      <h5><button type="button" class="txt-eliminar">Eliminar Trámite</button></h5>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

El error me sale en el valor ...[0]; dice que Cannot read property 0 of undefined
Espero me pueden ayudar, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No sé cómo es que sí se puede acceder al resto de campos como lo estás haciendo, pero, de entrada, `let padre = elemento.closest('.modal-body');` debería devolver nulo, porque el div de la ventana modal, realmente es hijo del formulario y [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) busca en los ancestros.

De hecho, el formulario que es el que dispara el evento y, por tanto, el elemento que debes usar para obtener todos los campos.

```js
$(".form-devolucion-dvl").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Usar el formulario para acceder a campos
  let padre = $(this);

  let idtramite = padre.find(".idtramite").val();
  let tramitedoc = padre.find(".documentot").val();
  let archivotra = padre.find(".frmfile").prop("files")[0];

  var datosactualizar = new FormData();
  datosactualizar.append("idtramite", idtramite);
  datosactualizar.append("tramitedoc", tramitedoc);
  datosactualizar.append("archivotra", archivotra);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "consultas/actualizar.php",
    data: datosactualizar,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(r) {
      r = r.trim();
      if (r == "true") {

        swal({
          type: 'success',
          title: 'Tramite Corregido con éxito'
        }).then(function() {
          location.reload();
        });

      } else if (r == "false") {

        swal({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Error al Actualizar, volver a intentar por favor'
        });

      }

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal form-devolucion-dvl mt-3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-body">

    <input type="hidden" name="frmid" class="idtramite" value="2" required="required" />
    <input type="hidden" name="frmdoc" class="documentot" value="archivos/hola.jpg" required="required" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="frmcorregir" disabled>Hola</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input frmfile" name="frmfile">
      <label class="custom-file-label form-control">Selecciona Archivo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
      <h5><button type="button" class="txt-eliminar">Eliminar Trámite</button></h5>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```